# Can't update is_active on user: user.update(is_active: true) fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`user.update(is_active: true)` works in the rails console, but not in the application.

This is from the sessions_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    username_or_email = params[:session][:username_or_email].downcase
    user = if username_or_email.include?("@")
      User.find_by(email: username_or_email)
    else
      User.find_by(username: username_or_email)
    end
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id 
      user.update!(is_active: true)
      redirect_to user_path(user.username)
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'sign_in'
    end
  end
```

I get this result:
`Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)`

Which seems strange, is the password supposed to be passed too?

Comment: Can you please share application_controller.rb as well ?

Comment: Thank you @maya_nk99 for looking at this. I have added the whole content of `application_controller.rb`.

Comment: Are you sure its not a "programmer related issue"? For example that you're not running the code that you think you are? Add a breakpoint and verify that the method is actually being called. I would also use `update!` here as this should not be expected to fail and you don't just want to let it fail silently.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Got an actual error now with `update!` so I've updated the question description.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass This error basically means the password associated with the user is invalid. Most probably you created this user by bypassing the model validations or you have updated your password validations after creating this user. In any case, when you try to do any update on the user now, the model validations are run and password validation is throwing error. 
The update from rails console should throw the same error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to bypass validation using `update_columns` instead.
This was because the user model had this validation:

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

I added `sign_in` and `sign_out` functions to the user model and handled it properly in those.